# Remove repetitive fragments from fragment manager in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am working on android using Xamarin and MVVMCross framework. I want to update the remove the fragment from fragment manager to handle the back button, Because i have to navigate between screen which make a cross reference in Back Stack. So i want to remove the repetitive entries from stack. Its removing the repetitive entries from stack but it does not update the BackStackEntryCount with latest fragments.

I have written code

```
   public override void OnFragmentChanged(IMvxCachedFragmentInfo fragmentInfo)
    {
        if (fragmentInfo != null)
        {
            var ifExists =
                SupportFragmentManager.Fragments?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Tag.ToLower() == fragmentInfo.Tag.ToLower());

            if (ifExists != null)
            {
                var indexOf = SupportFragmentManager.Fragments.IndexOf(ifExists);
                var total = SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount;
                for (int i = indexOf + 1; i < total; i++)
                {
                    SupportFragmentManager.Fragments.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnFragmentChanged(fragmentInfo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SupportFragmentManager.Fragments` is a read only property (It only has a `get`). Modifying the content of the list of fragment has no impact on the underline fragment backstack count.

What you can instead try is to pop the stack down to the existing fragment. This should remove all fragments above it.

```
var exisitngFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(fragmentInfo.Tag);
SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate(exisitngFragment.Id, 0);
```